# Simple AIR Notification App (noob)

Tags: javascript, html, air

I would like to create a simple AIR app that show's a notification on the bottom right of the users screen. this app won't show all of the time, it will just show if I push a new notification to the users computer. I am doing this in Dreamweaver. It will open on Windows XP computers only.

So far I have found out how to show a notification window with my html file:

```
notification.load( new air.URLRequest( HTML_SOURCE ) );
```

What I am not clear on is:

1. how to have this happen automatically on login.
2. how the AIR app can check if a new msg is available.
3. how best to exit the app

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For starting application on login, you have to set `air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.startAtLogin = true`
   For details u=you can have a look at this [adobe article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/quickstart/articles/startup_options.html).
2. You can store messages with a increasing message_id column. So when your application shows any message it can store that value as last_message_read in your data. Then you can use this value to check if new messages are available (You will have to save this variable in a file)
3. For exiting application you can use `air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();`
   or just close your main application window by `close()`. It will automatically close your application.